# squid forwarding proxy cache_peer connection check

Tags: proxy, squid

I have setup squid as a forwarding proxy and using 2 parent proxies as below:

```
cache_peer 192.168.1.1 parent 3128 0 no-query default
cache_peer 192.168.1.2 parent 3128 0 no-query default
```

The problem is sometimes some of these proxies will not connect to the requested url because of networking issues, actually there are some vpn tunnels between the proxies and the destination network i'm trying to reach and sometimes they go down beyond my control.

In access.log the following message is shown:

```
1613301454.610   1182 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/502 0 CONNECT 1.2.3.4:443 - FIRSTUP_PARENT/192.168.1.1 -
```

If I just switch the peers order in the squid config, everything works because the proxy 1.2 is properly connected to the destination network.

I want to be able to tell squid to try the second proxy if the first one is getting 502 response code on connect.

So my question here is how can I mark a proxy as 'bad/dead' based on the 502 or some other response codes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could be only one default?

```
cache_peer 192.168.1.1 parent 3128 0 no-query default
cache_peer 192.168.1.2 parent 3128 0 no-query
```